# How to download N number of files asynchronously using wget and node

Tags: javascript, node.js, wget

I have the following Node script:

```js
var exec = require('child_process').exec;

var download_file_wget = function(file_url) {
    // compose the wget command
    var wget = `wget ${file_url}`;

    // execute wget using child_process' exec function
    var child = exec(wget, function(err) {
        if (err) throw err;
        else console.log(`${file_url} downloaded`);
    });
};

download_file_wget('http://placekitten.com/10/10');
```

It does successfully download 1 file. I need to asynchronously download 128 files at once. How can I do this with this code?

Comment: In your code spawn and XMLHttpRequest it is not used for anything

Comment: yes it is used in the larger body which isnt relevant here

Comment: It helps if you only include the part of code that is useful

Answer (score 1):

If the files requested are big consider use spawn instead of exec.

```
const http = require('http');
const exec = require('child_process').exec;

const DOWNLOAD_DIR = './downloads/';

const generate_width_and_height = function() {
  const random = Math.floor((Math.random() * 100) + 200);
  console.log(random);
  return random
}

const create_file_url = function() {
  return "http://placekitten.com/" + generate_width_and_height() + "/" + generate_width_and_height() 
}

const oneHundredTwentyEightElementsArray = Array.from(Array(127), (_,x) => x);
const oneHundredTwentyEightUrlsArray = oneHundredTwentyEightElementsArray.map( _ => create_file_url())

const download_file_wget = function(file_url, file_number) {
  // extract the file name
  const file_name = "file_" + file_number
  // compose the wget command
  const wget = 'wget -P ' + DOWNLOAD_DIR + ' ' + file_url;

  // excute wget using child_process' exec function
  const child = exec(wget, function(err, stdout, stderr) {
    if (err) throw err;
    else console.log(file_name + ' downloaded to ' + DOWNLOAD_DIR);
  });
};

for (let index = 0; index < oneHundredTwentyEightElementsArray.length; index++) {
    const url = oneHundredTwentyEightUrlsArray[index];
    download_file_wget(url, index)
}
```

Comment: I needed it done asynchronously. I ended up using promises

Comment: child_process.exec() is asynchronous, child_process.execSync(): a synchronous version of child_process.exec() that will block the Node.js event loop.

https://nodejs.org/api/child_process.html#child_process_child_process_exec_command_options_callback

Answer (score 0):

You can use [Javascript Promises](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/Promise) to download multiple files with node and wget.

First wrap your inner code in a promise:

```js
const downloadFile = (url) => {
    return new Promise((resolve) => {
        console.log(`wget ${url} --no-check-certificate`)
        exec(`wget ${url} --no-check-certificate`, function(err, stdout, stderr) {
            if (err) {
                console.log('ERR', err, url)
            } else {
                console.log('SUCCESS ' + url);
                resolve(1)
            }
        });
    })
}
```

Then use Promise.all to process all the downloads asynchronously:

```
const files = [
  'http://placekitten.com/10/10',
  'http://placekitten.com/10/10'
  // etc
]
(async () => {
   await Promise.all(files.map(url => downloadFile(url)))
})()
```